# Not able to access pip host from Google cloud build

Tags: docker, ip, vpc, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to create a docker image using google cloud build but it is failing to access the pip host.

below is the line I'm getting error

```
RUN pip install -vvv --extra-index-url http://[pip host] --trusted-host [pip host] -r requirements.txt
```

```
Step #2: Step 7/10 : RUN pip install --extra-index-url http://[pip host] --trusted-host [pip host] -r requirements.txt
Step #2:  ---> Running in 1400ecddf71f2
Step #2: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, http://[pip host]/simple/
Step #2: Collecting [some package == version](from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Step #2:   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f58e9d64b70>, 'Connection to [pip host] timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/[some package]/
Step #2:   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f58e9d5a9e8>, 'Connection to [pip host] timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/[some package]/
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: pip host is a private host

Comment: could you share the cloudbuild.yaml, obviously editing any private information

Comment: cloudbuild.yaml             ```steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
     'build',
     '--network=cloudbuild',
     '-t',
     gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/image_name:$BRANCH_NAME', 
     '-f',
     'Dockerfile',
     '.'
        ]```

Comment: Dockerfile       ```RUN pip install --extra-index-url http://[pip host] --trusted-host [pip host] -r requirements.txt ```

Comment: could you try to ping the [pip host]? to see if its answering and accessible on that point

Comment: not able to ping

Comment: Actual problem is CloudBuild runs build on VM instance in worker pool,  that doesn't have access to the pip host instance.

Comment: If any one know how to use Custom worker pooli in a GCP project please share.

Comment: is your pip host accessible from the GCP network, could you try to ping it from cloud shell?

Comment: No i can't ping from cloud shell

Comment: ok, is the pip host one of the build steps or at part of the network created for the build process?